# Distance between Sun and Earth using JPL horizons

Tags: the-sun, jpl-horizons, ephemeris

Using the JPL Horizons app at https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/app.html#/ would someone help to calculate the distance between the Sun and the Earth say 1 May 2023 00:00 UT? I used the following for the calculation.

- 1 Ephemeris Type: Vector Table
- 2 Target Body: Sun
- 3 Coordinate Center: Bangalore India
- 4 Time Specification: 2023-05-01 00:00-2023-05-30 00:00
- 5 Table Settings: 6: '1-way light-time + range + range-rate'

For 6, we obtained the value RG= 1.506919214640888E+08 kms, or,
1.5069E+08/1.4960E+08 = 1.007 AU (Here, 1.4960E+08 is 1 AU). Thus, on May 1, 2023, the distance between the Sun and the Earth was 1.007 A.U., right?

This is to make sure that the parameter is calculated correctly.

Comment: The would be the distance between Bangalore and the Sun.  If you want the distance to the center of the Earth use @399 as the coordinate center.

Comment: Fine, thank you.

Comment: I proceeded with the suggestion, and 399 as the Coordinate Center fetched Kushiro (observatory) [code: 399]. Thank you.

Comment: The Kushiro Observatory is `399@399`. For the geocenter, use `@399` or `500@399`. Here's a Horizons API [query](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&OBJ_DATA=NO&EPHEM_TYPE=V&OUT_UNITS=AU-D&VEC_LABELS=NO&VEC_TABLE=6&CENTER=%40399&START_TIME=%272023-05-01+UT%27&STOP_TIME=2023-05-31&STEP_SIZE=1d&COMMAND=10)

Answer (score 2):

Without all the details and especially without the output included in the question, it's hard to say for sure that you've done things exactly correctly.

However I think you're certainly close!

This Python script uses the Skyfield package and the DE421 [Development Ephemeris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_Propulsion_Laboratory_Development_Ephemeris) While JPL's Horizons doesn't use *exactly* this same ephemeris, results will be very very close.

On May 1st 2023, with Bangalore at 12.979N, 77.592E I get  a distance to the Sun of 1.007313284 AU or 150691922.3 km. You will get slightly different numbers if you used a slightly different lat/lon, or if you included the light-time correction, I didn't use Skyfield's ['apparent()'](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/api-position.html#skyfield.positionlib.Astrometric.apparent) method that does a few more corrections.

[image: distance from Bangalore to the Sun in May 2023 using Skyfield]

```
from skyfield.api import Loader, Topos
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

load = Loader('~/Documents/fishing/SkyData') # avoid multiple copies of large files
ts = load.timescale()
eph = load('de421.bsp')

earth, sun, moon = [eph[x] for x in ('earth', 'sun', 'moon')]

latlon = 12.979, 77.592
bangalore = Topos(latitude_degrees = latlon[0],
                  longitude_degrees = latlon[1])

days = np.arange(1, 31)

times = ts.utc(2023, 5, days, 0, 0, 0) # 2023-05-01 00:00-2023-05-30 00:00

sun_astrometric = (earth + bangalore).at(times).observe(sun)

both = sun_astrometric.distance().au, sun_astrometric.distance().km

i_annotate = [0, 4, 9, 14, 19, 24, 29]

annots = [[str(val) for val in thing[i_annotate].round(n)]
          for (thing, n) in zip(both, (9, 1))]

annots = np.array(annots)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1)

goodies = axes, both, ('AU', 'km'), annots

for ax, distance, label, anns in zip(*goodies):
    ax.plot(days, distance)
    for ann, day, dist in zip(anns, days[i_annotate], distance[i_annotate]):
        ax.annotate(ann, (day, dist))
        ax.plot(day, dist, 'ok')
    ax.set_ylabel(label, fontsize=12)

axes[1].set_xlabel('days in May 2023', fontsize=12)

suptitle = ('distance from Bangalore ' + str(latlon) +
            ' to the Sun May 2023 (00:00)')

plt.suptitle(suptitle)

fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.13, right=0.86)
             
plt.show()
```

Comment: The Skyfield Code has rendered the plot beautifully. If we need to use to code for 500@399, how does the Code need to be modified, thank you.

Comment: @Smarty for 500@399 = Earth's geocenter, in the line that beings `sun_astrometric = ` just change `(earth + bangalore)` to `earth`. it's really that easy :-) Oh, and of course change the plot label text from "Bangalore" to "Geocenter". You can also create Skyfield's artificial satellite objects in orbit around Earth from TLEs and use `(earth + ISS)` just for example.

Comment: Thus, the following should be deleted, right:  `latlon = 12.979, 77.592 bangalore = Topos(latitude_degrees = latlon[0], longitude_degrees = latlon[1])`,  and this code need to me modified as`suptitle = ('distance from Bangalore ' + ' to the Sun May 2023 (00:00)')`.

Comment: @Smarty you can delete them or comment them out or leave them in place - they don't have any effect since `bangalore` is not used. In fact they might not even get executed if their output is not used; Python is pretty smart sometimes.

Comment: How to obtain the heliocentric ecliptic coordinate of the Earth on this instant, i.e., 2023-05-01 00:00-2023-05-30 00:00?